# Where to find software for Huawei E1552 modem?

Tags: drivers, 3g

It comes with "Mobile Partner" 16.001.06.01.500 software on internal disk, but this version is highly unstable. Is there any newer version?

Comment: Ah, did I misunderstand, you want the connection management software not the drivers?

Comment: I want both. They go in a single package, anyway.

Comment: Well the search shows multiple sources for the driver only.  And once you have the driver, you can use standard Windows dial-up to make a connection.  The connection managers are generally not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the UK, pretty much every Huawei stick I've seen comes preloaded with the mobile operator's customised version, and the operators themselves have updated versions available on their websites.

Only nuisance is the operator's versions are normally branded and modified to only allow access to their network.

Comment: I have a non-branded version (not SIM locked)